# My chain snapped ,need help

Tags: road-bike, chain, replacement

My chain broke today and I want to get a new replacement for it I just don't know what size I need my bike has 3 gears in front and 6 in the back which I'm guessing is an 18 speed and if you can leave any suggestions for a chain I will appreciate it preferably under $30 I just commute to school.

Comment: Why did your chain snap?  Were you standing to pedal, or did you crash?

Comment: @Criggie Yeah I was practicing wheelies

Comment: Go for a slightly higher spec chain then - none of this $10-$20 cheap stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should get to the bike shop and they get you a chain the size you need. If you don't want to go with you bike, take your older chain. For sure it is under 30$. I paid less than 20 for a SRAM chain not long ago.